# Margin of control in window from

Tags: winforms

I create a control like this:

```
public class MyTextBoxControl : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{
}
```

and I drag-drop MyTextBoxControl to a window form, default margin is "3, 3, 3, 3"

My question is "Can I change default margin when drag-drop my control to a form?"

I want set default margin is "5, 5, 5, 5" and when I drag-drop my control to a form, margin is "5, 5, 5, 5". NOT "3, 3, 3, 3"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to apply the [DefaultValueAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.defaultvalueattribute.aspx) to the property in your class, but I don't think you can since the property is [not virtual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.margin.aspx).